# how to store Multiple pattern parameter in variable and print ihe values of that variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have **str** variable in that string is there

var str = "The **1_raj** in SPAIN stays mainly**3_raj** in **1_raj**the plain **2_raj** **4_raj** **6_raj**_**1_raj**";

var res = str.match(/1_raj/g);

i want to store( 1_raj,2_raj,3_raj,4_raj,...etc ) in **res** variable so that i can get diffirent(1_raj,2_raj,3_raj,...) values in variable **res**

thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far? attach the fiddle with your code in which you're facing issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regular expression to get the result,

```
var res = str.match(/[0-9]{1}_raj/g);
```

To match from `0_raj`, `1_raj`, .. to `9_raj`

Change the value from bracket if your value is more than 9 like `10_raj`

```
var res = str.match(/[0-9]{2}_raj/g);
```

Now you can use the separate values by looping through array 'res'.

```
for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
   alert(res[i]); // here you will get each value separately, as you want.
}
```

Hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: yes it works   var res = str.match(/[0-9]_raj/g);   with it thanks BalaG

Comment: but now i want to store **seperate** values in array or variable so that i can check condition on each parameter(1_Raj,2_raj,...etc).. any suggestion

Comment: @RAj_RN it returns Array only. So `res ` is an array.